# No sound on new system installation

Tags: sound

I am on a fresh Ubuntu 22.10 installation on a new PC and experience no sound from my headset or anywhere else.

My PC seems to recognize that some sound device is there:

[image: screenshot of Sound Output notification showing Built-in Audio]

[image: screenshot of System Volume, Volume Levels, Output, System Settings]

[image: screenshot of a terminal window showing Intel snd_dha_intel]

`inxi -SMA` results:

```
Device-1: Intel driver: snd_hda_intel
  Device-2: NVIDIA GA106 High Definition Audio driver: snd_hda_intel
  Sound Server-1: ALSA v: k5.19.0-29-generic running: yes
  Sound Server-2: PipeWire v: 0.3.63 running: yes
```

I unmuted everything in Alsamixer including my headphone:

[image: screenshot of alsamixer]

Yet nothing. I understand that I should look at my drivers, but how?

Comment: I understand.

The most important probably is my result of inxi -SMA, which I edited.

I'm trying a lot but I have no idea what I must install or change to get a result